# How to connect handy terminal device to Java hibernate spring web application

Tags: java, web-applications

I created my web application using java spring hibernate with jpa.
Now I have request from my company.I need to connect handy terminal device to get data by reading QR code.That data will be shown on my web page and save to database from my page.I have no knowledge about connecting terminal device to the web application.Please share your knowledge how to connect the terminal device with my web application.
Thank all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may vary depending on the model of the scanner, etc that you have been given, but my general understanding is this (especially for a cheap scanner) :

The scanner connects to your computer using either USB or Bluetooth or whatever.  You can imagine that as far as the computer is concerned, it is effectively just another keyboard.

When you scan a barcode, the scanner reads it as a text string that it simply "types" down the line to the computer - again, just like a keyboard.  This means the scanner doesn't need to be set up to know anything about your computer nor application - it just sends the string.

The scanner should also be configurable to terminate the string with either Tab or Enter - eg, the user manual may have special barcodes for these options, so you simply scan whichever you want.

What this means for your app is that it also does not need to know that it's getting it's input from a scanner.  So operation is that you should start by firing the app up, and navigating it to the correct page.   That page should have one (or more) fields to receive the codes "typed in" by the scanner.

It will always be your job (or rather, the operator's job) to ensure that the cursor is on the correct field before each scan.

That page should also work with the Tab-or-Enter suffix that you chose for the scanner.  eg, if your web app page has just a single field for the code, then you would probably want to set the scanner to suffix with the Enter key in order to submit the form.  If this form re-displays ready for the next code, then your work process is simply 1) navigate to the page, 2) put the cursor on the code field, 3) scan (and form automatically submits/processes/re-displays), 4) scan again, 5) scan ........

Alternatively, if you need to enter additional details with each scan (eg, a customer address or something), then you'd want to set the scanner to Tab.  So your work process would be to 1) navigate to the page, 2) put the cursor on the code field, 3) scan, 4) complete the rest of the form

Comment: Thanks
Company do not give anything about terminal yet.I just prepare for collecting data about developing with terminal device.I cannot find on google about it.Thank you for your answering